# For loop is not behaving as expected, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
$emails =array() // This is an array of 4600 emails of which i am generating a batch range for each 1000 emails 

$batch= ceil(count($emails)/1000);  // i am getting how many batches i need to get

$lowe=0; //lower range for initialization

$upper=$lowe+999; //upper range for initialization


for ($i=0; $i < $batch; $i++) { 
            if ($i!=0) {
           $lowe=$upper+1;
           $upper=  $upper+$lowe;
     }

$ss[]=['lower'=>$lowe,'upper'=>$upper];

    }

return ($ss);  // response is [{"lower":0,"upper":999},{"lower":1000,"upper":1999},{"lower":2000,**"upper":3999},{"lower":4000,"upper":7999},{"lower":8000,"upper":15999}]**

// yet i expect [{"lower":0,"upper":999},{"lower":1000,"upper":1999},{"lower":2000,"upper":2999},{"lower":3000,"upper":3999},{"lower":4000,"upper":4999}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the assignment of $upper in the loop to a constant value

```
for ($i=0; $i < $batch; $i++) { 
    if ($i != 0) {
        $lowe = $upper + 1;
        $upper += 999;
    }
    $ss[]=['lower'=>$lowe,'upper'=>$upper];
}
```

Comment: it actually should be `$upper += 1000;`, not `$upper += 999;`

Comment: Thank you. Saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what you are doing wrong:

in the loop, `$lowe` keeps increasing in value - so when you do `$upper = $upper+$lowe;`, the difference between the old value of `$upper`and the new value also increases.

What you are aiming for is a constant increase of 1000 for your `$upper` value, that's why you have to replace `$upper = $upper+$lowe;` with `$upper += 1000`

Comment: Yes this solves the problem. Thanks you. Also I have discovered replacing $upper =$upper+$lowe; with $upper =$lowe+999; solves also the problem.